# Vim delete a command

Tags: vim

How do I delete a command that I created using the `:command` command?

I mis-typed:

```
:command Bigfon guifont=Monospace\ 12
```

So now I have a `Bigfon` command that doesn't work correctly; I'd like to just have a `Bigfont` command that does (`:command Bigfont set guifont=Monospace\ 12`)

Searches that involve both "Vim" and "delete" seem to only return pages that describe the various commands to delete text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delc Bigfon` or `delcommand Bigfon`.

Documentation `:h delc`:

```
:delc[ommand] {cmd}             *:delc* *:delcommand* *E184*
            Delete the user-defined command {cmd}.
```

Although there is a much better way to change font size quickly ( from [tpope's `.vimrc`](https://github.com/tpope/tpope/blob/e8f5d80cf46df8b962cd947a6575bd0621fd6da6/.vimrc#L408-L411) ):

```
" Quickly change gui font size with + and - in normal mode
command! -bar -nargs=0 Bigger  :let &guifont = substitute(&guifont,'\d\+$','\=submatch(0)+1','')
command! -bar -nargs=0 Smaller :let &guifont = substitute(&guifont,'\d\+$','\=submatch(0)-1','')
nnoremap - :Smaller<CR>
nnoremap + :Bigger<CR>
```